# Parse a map of int -> list from a string

Tags: python

This should be a fairly straight forward python question, but I'm getting stuck getting the syntax right.

Let's say I have a string:

```
"1:a,b,c::2:e,f,g::3:h,i,j"
```

and I want to convert this to a map like so:

```
{'1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], '2': ['e', 'f', 'g'], '3': ['h', 'i', 'j']}
```

How would this be done?

I can figure out how to do it using nested for loops, but would be cool to just do it in a single line.

Thanks!

Comment: hint: have a look at string's split method which you can use to break your input string into chunks that you can further work on (perhaps with more calls to split)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
dict((k, v.split(',')) for k,v in (x.split(':') for x in s.split('::')))
```

Comment: Horrible names, but otherwise perfect, +1

Comment: @delnan: not quite perfect, use of `list()` is redundant

Comment: @John Machin: Thanks for pointing that out. I wasn't sure if split returns a list in all versions of Python so was playing it safe. But I checked now and it seems that it always does. Fixed now. :)

Comment: I wasn't sure either if split returned a list. They made nearly everything an iterator in Python 3 (which is a good thing) ;)